# Use of socket which is not bound or bound but doesn't listen

Tags: sockets, posix

As side question, can `bind` and `listen` be reversed? E. g. I'd like to keep port or file descriptor for a while and then rebind and listen again?

I'm also curious about rationale of this design. In all examples I've seen, stream sockets are bound first and then start listening. I.e. `bind`, and `listen` are to be called separately whereas socket is not used between then in any ways. Is that because these calls are more or less separate and orthogonal from OS point of view?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `listen()` on an unbound socket, and you cannot `bind()` a socket that is already bound.  They are separate operations because `bind()` can be used for both clients and servers, whereas `listen()` can only be used for servers.